# Is there a angularJS datepicker for mobile?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I have found for a long time on google, but no good luck.
mobiscroll seems great, but it is not free.
ionic-datepicker can work, but its performance is not good.

I need to support some mobile browser which doesn't support H5, so  can not be used.

Is there any other choice? I hope the datepicker is similar to IOS native and can work on both ios and anroid

Answer (score 0):

I also finding

see this

xingchou/datePicker  https://github.com/xingchou/datePicker

and 720kb/angular-datepicker have a option `datepicker-mobile=""`

Answer (score -3):

Look this please............:

http://curioussolutions.github.io/DateTimePicker/